# Codeigniter 4 how to show if records where a certain name appears in more than X rows

Tags: codeigniter-4

I would like to ask how do I show if a particular name appears for more than X rows in my table.

For mySQL query :
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE fieldname = 2;

For CI4, is it the same like this :
$users = $userModel->asObject('count')->where('fieldname', '2')->findAll();

If not, can anyone tell me what is the right query for CI4? Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve it by using

```
$users = $model->where('fieldname', '2')
                ->countAllResults();
```

Hope this helps someone out there.